# Use multinomial-dist to express a distribution

Tags: racket

I have to use `multinomial-dist` in order to express the following distribution:

| x | P(x) |
| --- | --- |
| red | 0.5 |
| blue | 0.05 |
| green | 0.4 |
| black | 0.05 |

Where P(x) refers to the probability of x. 
I implemented the following solution in Dr.Racket using Gamble:

```
(define color '("red" "blue" "green" "black"))

(define (color-probability color)
  (cond
    [(equal? "red") 0.5]
    [(equal? "blue") 0.05]
    [(equal? "green") 0.4]
    [else 0.05]))

(define my-color (multinomial-dist color color-probability))
(dist-sample my-color)
```

But it returns an error:

```
make-multinomial-dist: contract violation
  expected: natural?
  given: '("red" "blue" "green" "black")
  in: the 1st argument of
      (->
       natural?
       (vectorof (>=/c 0))
       multinomial-dist?)
```

I'm new in Racket and i'm still learning the basics and i don't understand what the compiler didn't like!

Thank you all!

Comment: In DrRacket, right-clicking on a selection (eg `multinomial-dist`) and choosing "Search in Help Desk..." will show links to documentation. The arguments to `multinomial-dist` are `n` (sample count, a Natural) and `weights` (a Vectorof Number, but apparently _not_ the **P(x)** values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation entry for `multinomial-dist`, viewed from DrRacket by selecting multinomial-dist, right clicking on it, choosing `Search in Help Desk for "multinomial-dist"` (**do this for each new function in what follows**) is:

```
(struct multinomial-dist (n weights))
  n : exact-nonnegative-integer?
  weights : (vectorof (>=/c 0))
```

> Represents a multinomial distribution. The support consists of vectors of the same length as weights representing counts of n iterated samples from the corresponding categorical distribution with weights for weights.

So a multinomial-dist can be constructed by an expression, for example, like:
`(multinomial-dist 100 (vector 49 51))`
(the `(vector 49 51)` could be the result of 100 *iterated samples* from a
*categorical distribution* with *weights* `(vector 50 50)` eg representing a coin toss)

The **P(x)** values in the question are categorical distribution (sometimes called
discrete distribution) weights, so start with this:

```
#lang racket
(require Gamble)

(define color-dist (categorical-dist (vector 0.5 0.05 0.4 0.05)))
```

To try this out, `sample` the distribution a few times in DrRacket's interaction area:

```
> (sample color-dist)
0
> (sample color-dist)
2
> (sample color-dist)
0
>
```

One way to construct *iterated* samples in Racket is with `build-list`:

```
(define samples (build-list 100 (lambda (x) (sample color-dist))))

> samples
'(3 0 0 2 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 1 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 1 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 1 2 0 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1 1 0 3 0 2 2 2 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 3 0)
>
```

*Counts* of these samples are required (when needing a function, one can just type in a likely name and use "Search in Help Desk"...); try it out:

```
> (count (lambda (n) (= n 0)) samples)
51
>
```

The weights are required as a vector, so add:

```
(define weights
  (vector (count (lambda (n) (= n 0)) samples)
          (count (lambda (n) (= n 1)) samples)
          (count (lambda (n) (= n 2)) samples)
          (count (lambda (n) (= n 3)) samples)))

> weights
'#(51 6 40 3)
>
```

(After learning Scheme/Racket basics, one can eliminate the repetition in the definition above)

And then, finally,

```
> (multinomial-dist 100 weights)
(multinomial-dist 100 '#(51/100 3/50 2/5 3/100))
>
```

Comment: Disclaimer: the answer above was produced without experience of Gamble/probabilistic programming, and may not address the requirement to "express the distribution"

Answer (score 0):

The distribution you're supposed to represent is not a multinomial distribution, which is a distribution over *vectors*.

I think you need to use `discrete-dist` instead.

Comment: I tried but does not work, in addiction I am asked to use the multinomial

Comment: @Eli - does the assignment suggest using Gamble's `multinomial-dist`, or just refer to the given **P(x)** as a multinomial distribution? can you clarify "...express a distribution" - what sort of output should the answer produce?

Comment: Yes, the assignment just using `multinomial-dist`, but the output is not specified. P(x) refers to the probabilities of x, for example red has a probability of 0.5